# Why is the VGA Cable attached to new monitors

Tags: display

When opening a new monitor I am amazed that the VGA cable is always attached. Even with new high end monitors that include Display Port and DVI cables the old VGA cable is always attached while the others are just left in the box.

What is the reasoning behind attaching a cable in the first place and why the VGA cable in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not everybody has a graphics card with DVI and, especially, DisplayPort.

And not everybody makes a connection between these connectors and a monitor, unfortunately; everybody's gotten used to VGA, because it was (and still is) used on older monitors, quite a lot of modern LCD TVs and a lot of projectors.

Answer (score 3):

They tested it that way before they shipped it.  Why spend any more time to disconnect the cable?  There are another thousand to test today.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking - it's a QA thing before packaging

Answer (score 2):

People are stupid. There isn't really anyway to get around that. Some people wouldn't know where to plug that same cable in on the computer if it wasn't color coded.

This is a little pessimistic, but I would imagine "user friendliness" is part of it, so that the most commonly used connection is the easiest for the layman to use.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that perhaps it's manufacturing throw-back it's easier to hot-swap VGA than DVI, so the monitors are probably tested then packed.

There are also known issues with some-monitors and NVidia cards where they will not detect DVI unless forced - VGA simply always works.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking - it's a QA thing before packaging

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it has something to do with the fact the older monitors came with a built-in VGA cable (no connectors).
Maybe the people who package the new monitors want to be consistent `:-)`